# Render mobile version of login in Secure class Play! Framework

Tags: security, mobile, authentication, playframework

Is it possible to somehow override the login method of the Secure.java class of the Secure-Module in Play! Framework, so that another version of the login form is displayed?

In my case, i want to display a mobile version of the login-form if a mobile browser is detected.

I know i should not change the Secure.java class itself, but i don't really see any other solution to this problem.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be allowed to change the Secure.java class? If that's what your application needs then do it. The Secure module is quite simple after all, there's no way it can handle all different situations possible. Hack away :)

Comment: the problem is that I work in a team with some of my colleagues, and the changings would not be uploaded into svn (cause secure is a module = not on svn). i solved it now by simply copying the login and authenticate methods into my Security class and modified it for my mobile needs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in other [posts](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/play-framework/h4cHhGQaarw) you have the `request`  in your Play! controller. So in this request you could ask which agent is trying to view your website:

```
String agentInfo = request.headers.get("user-agent");
```

The you can determine which template will be rendered for this agent:

```
if (agentType.isWhatEverHeIs) {
  renderTemplate("Application\mobileTemplateForBadPractise.html");   
} else {
  render();
}
```

But what I would encourage you to do is `responsive` webdevelopment. Create your templates as smart as possible, let the template and css and javascript do this and keep your business logic in your controller.

You could use the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) to achieve this, but there are many more! Like [Skeleton](http://www.getskeleton.com/).

You even got the `request` object inside your templates so that you can optionally render things in your template (or not) based on the agent.

Answer (score 0):

Even simpler, simply create/override the `secure/login.html` template and use responsive design : media queries. No need to change the controller or check agent or whatever.